# Curve_fit - Set maximum allowed error for a given coefficient returned during fitting for a model function

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am using `scipy.curve_fit` to fit a sum of gaussian functions to histogram data taken from an experiment. I can get a decent enough looking overall fit, with an acceptable combined Root-Mean-Sqaure-Error for the fit model as a whole, but I would like to do more with the individual root mean square error on each derived coefficient as it propagates to later calculations. I am using the var_matrix returned from curve_fit to extract the RMSE for each individual parameter.

Is it possible to set a maximum error allowed per coefficient during fitting e.g. 10% of a given coefficients value. I have initial guess parameters and bounds for each coefficient, but My concern is I have 21 fitted coefficients and some of them have miniscule error while others have errors larger than the coefficient value it's self which leads me to believe the fitting is done solely based on the total error of the model, which may be "shoving" a lot of error on a given coefficient to make it easier for the other parameters.

Comment: Technically, that is possible, but not with `curve_fit`. One might change the gradient of the LM according to errors of fit parameters. Reading the last part, however, there might be some misconception. `curve_fit` is not minimizing the error of the fit parameters, but chi^2. Having few parameters having large errors can have different reasons. 1) The model is wrong/incomplete. 2) The data is insufficient to estimate that specific parameter. 2) The data is independent of that parameter. 4) High correlation with other parameters; check also the off diagonal elements of the covariance matrix.

Comment: ...on the other hand, from what you are doing, I think you know that. So what is actually bothering you?

Comment: Hi @mikuszefski , Thanks for the suggestion, I just converted it to an lmfitmodel in my code. Yes I understand that chi squared is being minimized, I have noisy data in this fit but know the approximate peak values (gauss amp,mu,sigma) from a fit to a dataset with less noise. What I would like to do is (in any method, curvefit,lmfit...) perform a fit with boundaries on the coefficients and on top of that put a boundary on max uncertainty of a given coeff even if that sacrifices models overall chi squared. In a sense I agree with you, if one coeff is completly uncertain model fit is meaningless

Comment: Basically I want to spread out uncertainty to other parameters so that each has some acceptable (believable) value, if one goes off the charts the whole fit is wrong

Comment: Well then, as I said, it is technically possible, but not with those high level functions. I'd like to point out, though, that I do not think that the ansatz is a good idea. Forcing the parameters to have similar errors does not make the fit better.